# How to set ons-sliding-menu inside ons-navigator via Angular ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, onsen-ui

I want to load `ons-sliding-menu` inside the `ons-navigator` via `angular ui-router`, but it's not working. Please have a look on my below code, where i am doing wrong, and why it's happening, neither its showing any error in the console nor its working. Your help's will be really appreciated.

**Angular :-**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['onsen', 'ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/slider');

    $stateProvider      
        .state('navigator', {
            abstract: true,
            url: '/navigator'
        })
        .state('navigator.slider', {
            parent: 'navigator',
            url: '/slider',
            onEnter: ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
                $rootScope.myNavigator.resetToPage('html/slider.html');
            }]
        })
    ;

});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator"></ons-navigator>

    <ons-template id="html/slider.html">
        <ons-sliding-menu menu-page="html/menu.html" 
                          side="left" 
                          main-page="html/main.html" 
                          var="myMenu" type="reveal" 
                          max-slide-distance="260px" 
                          swipeable="true">
        </ons-sliding-menu>
    </ons-template>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ui-router is not working if there is no `ui-sref` in `index.html`.
Adding the next dumb div to your `index.html` makes it work.

```
<div style="height: 0; width: 0" ui-sref="navigator"></div>
```

It doesn't matter the state it points to as long as it exists. To be honest, I don't know the reason but it works with this workaround.

By the way, add an `ons-page` wrapping your `ons-sliding-menu` or the navigator will yell at you.

Hope it helps!